# How to pass javascript variable using amchary URL

Tags: javascript, php

```
 function custom(vall)
 {

   var chart;


  // create chart
   AmCharts.ready(function() {
    alert(vall);
  // load the data
 var chartData =   AmCharts.loadJSON('http://localhost/vivek/daydata.php?data=vall');                                                   

  // SERIAL CHART    
 chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
 chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
 chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "hrs";
 chart.theme = "none";
 chart.type = "serial";
}
```

var chartData = AmCharts.loadJSON('http://localhost/vivek/daydata.php?date=vall');
i want pass vall in this url, but it's not take value,in url showing only vall variable not value.

Answer (score 0):

I think below should work for you.Take out val variable form quotes.

AmCharts.loadJSON("http://localhost/vivek/daydata.php?data="+vall);